# HttpClient to HttpWebRequest

Tags: async-await, task-parallel-library, dotnet-httpclient

I build an application using HttpClient using .Net 4.5 Framework, but later I realized the clients machine is Windows Server 2003 which does not support .Net 4.5, so what are my options?

rewrite the application using HttpWebRequest? or, is there a better alternative?

Comment: Windows Server 2003 is nearing its end-of-life *fast* so the customer had better upgrade. Otherwise, you can use the [Microsoft.BCL.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) package that adds some .NET 4.5 features like `async/await` and `HttpClient` to 4.0 applications

Comment: HttpClient is also supported in .net 4 by referencing the nuget package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http/